# implode(): Passing glue string after array is deprecated. Swap the parameters

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, lampp

I am using xampp in linux(ubuntu).I have installed php7.4 and php5.6,I switch the php version as per project.This particular error I got is in laravel project(version 5.5) when I tried to upload data.I have  updated "fzaninotto/faker" as well.The project was running well in my previous os(windows) and now in linux it is showing this error.If it is due to php version then I switched to 5.6 version as well but error is same.

[image]

Comment: It's because you are running php 7.4.... that error comes because it's deprecated... you just need to switch the parameters

Comment: What isn't clear about that error message?

Answer (score 2):

### implode changed in php7.4

[image: Changelog php7.4 function implode]

Before php7.4 you could have the order of parameters be in any order.

The only way to have this error thrown is if you are using php >= 7.4

Comment: @Artisan I switched between  php version in my system but still getting same error.I have installed php 5.6 and php7.4 both and for this project I switched to php5.6.

Comment: It will not throw this error for pho < 7.4 try doing <?php phpinfo();